How to parse soap xml file in php using simplexml_load_string
I am trying to parse an EDI xml file obtained from webservice via SOAP. I get the result as an xml. But i can not parse the result.
This is what i get as a response :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap: Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap: Body><ListMBResponse xmlns="http://www.comarch.com/"><ListMBResult><Res>00000000</Res><Cnt><mailbox-response><document-info><partner-iln>123</partner-iln><tracking-id>{7878}</tracking-id><document-type>ORDERS</document-type><document-version>TR</document-version><document-standard>XML</document-standard><document-test>P</document-test><document-status>R</document-status><document-number>2005919</document-number><document-date>2024-07-29</document-date><document-control-number>61870</document-control-number><receive-date>2024-07-29 22:30:36</receive-date></document-info><document-info><partner-iln>123</partner-iln><tracking-id>{7879}</tracking-id><document-type>ORDERS</document-type><document-version>TR</document-version><document-standard>XML</document-standard><document-test>P</document-test><document-status>R</document-status><document-number>2005870</document-number><document-date>2024-07-29</document-date><document-control-number>871</document-control-number><receive-date>2024-07-29 22:30:36</receive-date></document-info><document-info><partner-iln>123</partner-iln><tracking-id>{e7878}</tracking-id><document-type>ORDERS</document-type><document-version>TR</document-version><document-standard>XML</document-standard><document-test>P</document-test><document-status>R</document-status><document-number>2005887</document-number><document-date>2024-07-29</document-date><document-control-number>1864</document-control-number><receive-date>2024-07-29 22:30:34</receive-date></document-info></mailbox-response></Cnt></ListMBResult></ListMBResponse></soap:Body></soap: Envelope>

I tried using the simplexml_load_string and got the following :
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["ListMBResponse"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["ListMBResult"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
      ["Res"]=>
      string(8) "00000000"
      ["Cnt"]=>
      string(10978) "<mailbox-response><document-info><partner-iln>123</partner-iln><tracking-id>{7878}</tracking-id><document-type>ORDERS</document-type><document-version>TR</document-version><document-standard>XML</document-standard><document-test>P</document-test><document-status>R</document-status><document-number>2005919</document-number><document-date>2024-07-29</document-date><document-control-number>61870</document-control-number><receive-date>2024-07-29 22:30:36</receive-date></document-info><document-info><partner-iln>123</partner-iln><tracking-id>{7879}</tracking-id><document-type>ORDERS</document-type><document-version>TR</document-version><document-standard>XML</document-standard><document-test>P</document-test><document-status>R</document-status><document-number>2005870</document-number><document-date>2024-07-29</document-date><document-control-number>871</document-control-number><receive-date>2024-07-29 22:30:36</receive-date></document-info><document-info><partner-iln>123</partner-iln><tracking-id>{e7878}</tracking-id><document-type>ORDERS</document-type><document-version>TR</document-version><document-standard>XML</document-standard><document-test>P</document-test><document-status>R</document-status><document-number>2005887</document-number><document-date>2024-07-29</document-date><document-control-number>1864</document-control-number><receive-date>2024-07-29 22:30:34</receive-date></document-info></mailbox-response>"
    }
  }
}

What I am trying is to get/extract (loop) each data in "CNT" block. Specifically :
document-info
partner-iln
tracking-id
document-type
document-version
document-standard
document-test
document-status
document-number
document-date
document-control-number
receive-date

PHP has a SOAP Client extension. Additionally the XML does not match the debug output. In the debug output the Cnt contains a serialized, wellformed xml document without namespaces - this would require separate parsing. The XML example contains descendant nodes, this would make the nodes part of the namespace.
